# Get just the contents of an external directory in SVN

Tags: svn

I have a Libraries directory in my working directory. I would like to have an external property that  links to another Libraries directory.... just the contents of that directory.

existing:

```
../foo/bar/Libraries
      /Lib1
      /Lib2
```

external:

```
../Jim/bean/Libraries
      /LibA
      /LibB
```

The desired end result would be a Libraries directory in the working directory would contain the contents of both Libraries directories (Lib1, Lib2, LibA, and LibB).

If I add and external to bar Libraries gets overwritten by the jim/bean/Libraries. If I add a external to Libraries I end up with Libraries/Libraries.

I could add an external for each LibA, LibB in jim/bean/Libraries.... but that doesn't sound fun. Or I could just copy everything from jim/bean/Libraries and then ignore them... but that doesn't sound fun either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mix and have in one node (`bar/Libraries`) physical and logical object at the same time. Period. You can add childs only or restructure tree and collect full Libraries in another place (mounted as externals later to `bar/`)